# Insert multiple lines from QTextEdit into Jinja2 template

Tags: html, pyqt, jinja2, line-breaks, qtextedit

I have a QTextEdit that has several lines (Name, Age, Height).

```
self.textbox = QTextEdit(self)
self.textbox.setPlainText('Name:\n Age: \nHeight: \n')
self.enteredText = self.textbox.toPlainText()
```

I want to put this information into a Jinja2 HTML template so it shows in the following way:

> Personal data:
> Name: (whatever the user wrote after "name")
> Age: (whatever the user wrote after "age")
> Height: (whatever the user wrote after "height")

I'm having issues with linebreaks, I'm not sure how to process my `QTextEdit` so that I also get the linebreaks in HTML. I tried `self.enteredText.splitlines(True)` but HTML does not understand `\n` as linebreak and my text is all in one line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know almost nothing about jinja html templates, but you could try joining the lines together using `br` tags:

```
lines = '<br/>'.join(self.enteredText.splitlines()).
```